# rsync ssh sshpass server1 server2

Tags: ssh, rsync, sshpass

I have created 2 servers, new to ssh sshpass
s1 ip 192.168.1.245
s2 ip 192.168.1.76
wanted to copy files in s1>>/opt/files to s2>>/home/s2/backup

objective: put 1 sentence in cron to do auto rsync

i have these method

1)
using ssh rsa key method, genkey and copy over the key
it works for direct access. doesnt meet my need for rsync files
perhaps i did wrong or missing steps or issue wrong commands

2)
tried SSHPASS
can store pass but still doesnt work

3)
SSH + SSHPASS
getting all kinds of error

The above 3 methods are google using SSH without password and SSHPASS without password

Any expert could provide me with one line command or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave the password blank when generating the private keys, if you do so, it will not ask for a password when establishing the connection later.

rsync should work if you can establish a connection for "direct access" without a password, as long as you are using the same user (crontab -e). If you are running this from a root crontab (/etc/crontab or /etc/cron.*) then you also need to make rsync/ssh use the correct identity, you can do so with:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa" /source/folder/ username@server:/destination/folder/
```

Comment: rsync -av -e "ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa" /source/folder/ username@server:/destination/folder/

Will attempt shortly
Thanks for advice

Comment: I love you babe, you had solved my problem in a nite that i had been googling for answers with SSH SSHPASS even tried UNISON for the pass 2weeks.

Thank you very much